# What is a .psproj file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I cloned a repo and in it I got a `.psproj` file. I tried opening in Visual Studio 2017 (since notepad++ showed it contained xml much like VS Solutions). In VS also it opened showing internal xml and not as a proj/solution file. Same outcome with VS Code.

So my question is

1. What is a `psproj` file?
2. Since it was contained in a PowerShell folder, so is my assumption correct that it is a powershell project file?
3. What is the IDE to view these projects?

The file's contents:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>6CAFC0C6-A428-4d30-A9F9-700E829FEA51</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>MyApplication</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>MyApplication</AssemblyName>
    <Name>Bootstrapper</Name>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Script.ps1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Target Name="Build" />
</Project>
```

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://fileinfo.com/extension/psproj)

Comment: @un-lucky: I am pretty sure this is not the same.

Comment: @Downvoters : Care to explain what is wrong with the question.

Comment: Check the file's history. Perhaps someone renamed the file as a means of backup or whatever.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Are you saying no one will ask questions around psproj files in future? Just because it has not been asked in past does not mean it will not be asked in future. There is always a first time. Tell me one good link on psproj file and I'll be happy to delete the question. This question was asked after due investigation on google and stackoverflow and I have done investigation on my part by opening in VS and VS Code.

Comment: Not if it's a made up extension. PowerShell projects have the `.pssproj` extension. Did you do as I asked, did you check the file's history? Isn't there a colleague you can ask about this repository, or is there any documentation for it? Your research also isn't visible in your question, you didn't mention it's _not_ a PostMan project, for example.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Yes the code history has only one commit with comment `Initial commit` which is infact my modus operandi too. See reading your comment tells me that there is a Postman project too which I didn't knew earlier.

Comment: I suspect it to be a projectfile related to [PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio 2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdamRDriscoll.PowerShellToolsforVisualStudio2015) due to the  ProjectGuid but that tool seems to name their files slightly different.

Comment: ^ if this gets like 50 votes imma delete my answer lol

Comment: nikhil if you read mine it says just that... imma just delete screw it lol

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal meh, I'm not going to collect rep for doing a Google search for you.

Comment: @rene literally what i did too. and from my own knowledge of working, le google was to confirm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so going by the comments on questions, it is a powershell project file.

To enable your VS to understand such files, one needs to install respective extension to your [VS2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdamRDriscoll.PowerShellToolsforVisualStudio2015) or [VS2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdamRDriscoll.PowerShellToolsforVisualStudio2017-18561) or [VS2013](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdamRDriscoll.PowerShellToolsforVisualStudio2013)

Nice article on this is [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a30324/powershell-project-in-visual-studio/)

Answer (score 10):

It's a powershell project file, but not for Visual Studio, it's for Powershell Studio.  The powershell projects for visual studio are .pssproj.  It took me forever to figure this out because everyone here was too busy arguing about whether this was a valid question to pro